# File not found in an asp hosting

Tags: asp.net, url

I recently uploaded an asp web site on aspspider , I uploaded to the webroot two files

```
UniversityRDF.rdf
UniversityRDFS.rdf
```

But for unknown reason to me , I can't reach them when I browse to

```
www.aspspider.ws/#####/UniversityRDFS.rdf
or
www.aspspider.ws/#####/UniversityRDF.rdf
```

how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

IIS might not be configured to allow rdf files to pass through.  If you put a simple html file, can you see that?